# $w(x,f)=\bigcap_{m \geq 0} \overline{\bigcup_{n \geq m}f^n(x) }$

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

> Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $f : X \to X$ be continuous. I need to show that $$w(x,f)=\bigcap_{m \geq 0} \overline{\bigcup_{n \geq m}f^n(x) }$$
>   where $w(x,f)$ is the set of limit points of $O_f(x)=\{f^n(x):n \geq 0 \}.$

I'm able to show that $$w(x,f)\subseteq\bigcap_{m \geq 0} \overline{\bigcup_{n \geq m}f^n(x) }$$

However, for the reverse inclusion,  I'm not sure this is true if $O_f(x)$ is finite.

> If $O_f(x)$ is finite, then $w(x,f)=\emptyset$ and $$\overline{\bigcup_{n \geq m}f^n(x) }=O_f(x)$$ for each $m \geq 0.$ Thus, $$\bigcap_{m \geq 0} \overline{\bigcup_{n \geq m}f^n(x) }=O_f(x)$$

Where am I making a mistake? Does it have to do something with $X$ being compact?

Comment: When the orbit is a finite set it coincides with its $\omega$-limit set.

Comment: @JohnB But a finite set has no limit points.

Comment: Actually it does. What is then your definition of *limit point*?

Comment: @JohnB $y$ is a limit point of $A,$ if every neighbourhood of $y$ intersects with $A \setminus \{y\}.$

Comment: I see. That's not the canonical notion in dynamics, unless we agree that we consider different iterates giving the same point as distinct (but that's not usually done). If that's the definition that you were given the statement is false (for any orbit that is eventually periodic).

Comment: @JohnB I see. We weren't given a specific definition of a limit point in the current course, so I assumed the definition which we studied in metric space/topology.

Comment: Have a look for example at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_set. Actually your formula is the usual notion. The notion that could have perhaps have been given instead uses sequences. The wikipedia article is actually incorrect for the same reason that you noted when it talks about cluster points!

Comment: @JohnB So basically defining, $w(x,f)=\overline{O_f(x)}$ would have been more accurate.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is that the usual definition is $w(x,f)=\bigcap_{m \geq 0} \overline{\bigcup_{n \geq m}f^n(x) }$. In the case of a finite orbit indeed this gives the orbit.